# jQuery Mobile - events not fired on pagecontainer change

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to scroll to a particular div on the loading of a page. Jquery Mobile 1.4.
It works fine if you just load the page, but doesn't work if you load using the API.

Load using the API.

```
$('#schedule-a-call-collapsible').on("collapsibleexpand", function(event, ui){
        $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", 'schedule-a-call-mobile.html', {transition: 'slideup'} );
}
```

The scroll is just

```
Behave.prototype.doScrollTop = function(element) {
  var pos = $(element).offset().top;
  pos -= $('div.ui-header-fixed').outerHeight();
  $("html, body").animate({ "scrollTop": pos }, 500);
};
```

The event doesn't get fired.

```
jQuery('body').on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
    console.log("scrolling timezone");
    console.log(jQuery('#schedule-a-call-timezone').offset().top);
    $('#schedule-a-call-timezone-col').collapsible('expand');
    behave.doScrollTop(jQuery('#schedule-a-call-timezone-col'));
});
```

The rationale is that on expanding the collapsible the flow just got more complicated. I'd like to hide the other collapsible options unless someone scrolls and step through the workflow as if it was a new set of pages.

Thanks
John

Comment: Where are you placing code of `pagecontainershow`?

Comment: Doesn't matter if I put it at the bottom of the data-role=page or before close body </body>

Comment: I don't think it is possible and just set location.href. The jqm doc says that you can't load multi-page html using any transitions - which is what this is. Can't ajax load page collection and because it is ajax loading just one, it doesn't run 'pagecontainershow'.

Comment: Are you mixing between single and multi-page models?

Comment: Going from one pagecontainer to another. It's a sub-workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to just use location.href.

```
$('body').delegate('#collapsible-schedule-a-call', "collapsibleexpand", function (e, ui) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location.href = 'schedule-a-call-mobile.html';
});
```

The event listened for was changed so that it avoids the pagecontainershow event completely.

The root cause is trying to make a site that has mobile transitions that are different from desktop transitions (slide left on mobile etc). jquery mobile is a challenge when there are other frameworks involved.